# What is the equivalent of grep -wf in awk?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I need to search a list of items (handled as exact words) in `file1` such as:

```
RYK
RELA
CCNB1
RXRG
CREB1
ACREB1
CREB1B
```

in a `file2` with multiple columns, as for example

```
KIAA0196 FAM21C
BIRC2 UBE2D2
BIRC3 UBE2D2
BIRC7 UBE2D2
XIAP UBE2D2
BRCA1 UBE2D2
CDK5R1 HSP90AA1
ICAM1 ITGB2
RYK CDK1
CSNK2A1 CDK1
NFKB1 RELA
CREB1 JUN
PPME1 NFKB1
ARID4A CDK1
ICT1 TFAM
EZH2 CDK1
CDK1 EZH2
CDK1 EZH2
CDK1 HIST1H1D
CDK1 EZH2
CDK1 EZH2
CDK1 EZH2
BCL6 E2F3
CDK1 CCNB1
MME PDIA5
PPP2R1B CDK1
PPP2R1A CDK1
PPP2R1A CDK1
PPP2R1B CDK1
NCOR2 RXRG
THRB RXRG
RARA RXRG
RARB RXRG
RARG RXRG
PPARD RXRG
HDAC5 CDK1
CDK1 RUNX1
CREBBP CREB1
SSSSS CREB1-C
dddd A-CREB1
```

in order to get as output all lines containing at least one exact word in file1.

I usually make use of `grep -wf file1 file2` (`-w` for "matches that form whole words" and `-f` for "patterns from file, one per line"), simple and apparently efficient, and I have the following results:

```
RYK CDK1
NFKB1 RELA
CREB1 JUN
CDK1 CCNB1
NCOR2 RXRG
THRB RXRG
RARA RXRG
RARB RXRG
RARG RXRG
PPARD RXRG
CREBBP CREB1
SSSSS CREB1-C
dddd A-CREB1
```

One issue with `-w` is that (from `man grep`) "the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a *non-word constituent character*. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore". So, in the example above, `A-CREB1` and `CREB1-C` match `CREB1`, which is unwanted behaviuor.

I was looking for a `awk` one-liner (well, roughly, even a few lines would do) to do the same thing without the above issue.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Most people who use `grep -w` are actually doing the wrong thing as they're searching across a whole line instead of searching within a specific field and then just hoping a matching word won't show up in the wrong part of the line and so cause a false match. So do you have specific fields you want checked or truly all words on each line? It's also not clear if you want to consider "words" as space-separated strings or strings separated by "non-word-constituent-characters" like punctuation marks as well as spaces. Which do you want? Explain what you want to do, not just what `grep -w` does.

Comment: Trying to rephrase that better - creating an awk script to output what `grep -w` outputs given  that input isn't the same thing as creating an awk script to do what `grep -w` does in general so it's important for you to tell us what you're looking for an awk script to do - produce that output from that input or exactly mimic all of `grep -w`s behavior.

Comment: what version(s) of `awk` do you have access to? `gawk`, `nawk`, `mawk`, something else?  what does `awk --version` return?

Comment: @EdMorton usually i need to search the entire line but sometimes it happens that i need to narrow the search to a specific field or column. Words are usually space-, tab- or comma-separated strings. Most of the time, the optimal result for me is to find matches between the words in file1 (e.g., a list of genes coming from an experiment) and the line in file2 (e.g., a list of associations between two genes, for example an interaction between gene in column1 and gene in column2).

Comment: @markp-fuso I got `GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)`

Comment: You should [edit] your question to ask for help doing whatever it is you really want to do in awk because if your question really is `I was wondering if there is a way to do this in awk syntax as simple as the grep one.` the answer is either "yes" or "no" depending on what you're trying to do and how simple you feel it is for you to do it. If you're really asking if you can do the same thing `grep -w` does as **briefly** in awk then that's just "no".

Comment: @EdMorton I edited the question to make it (hopefully) more compliant with your remarks and added the mention of a problem with grep that I didn't realize before.

Comment: See the awk script in [@karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70465232/1745001) for what you want to do (which is not at all what `grep -wf` does, that's what markp-fuso's script does).

Answer (score 2):

One idea using `GNU awk` (or any `awk` that supports [GNU Regex Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html)):

```
awk '
FNR==NR  { regexes["\\y" $0 "\\y"]       # build and store regexs using "\y" to designate a word boundary
           next
         }
         { for (regex in regexes)        # loop through list of regexes
               if ( $0 ~ regex) {        # if regex matches anywhere in the line then ...
                  print $0               # print the line to stdout and ...
                  break                  # break out of loop (ie, keep us from printing the line multiple times for multiple regex matches)
               }
         }
' file1 file2
```

Running this against OP's sample input files gives us:

```
RYK CDK1
NFKB1 RELA
CREB1 JUN
CDK1 CCNB1
NCOR2 RXRG
THRB RXRG
RARA RXRG
RARB RXRG
RARG RXRG
PPARD RXRG
CREBBP CREB1
```

---

Using a different set of inputs to demonstrate word boundaries:

```
$ cat f1
ABC
DEF

$ cat f2
ABC DEF
DEF ABC
DEF ABC XYZ
DEF|ABC XYZ
ABCDEF
DEFABC
XYZ{ABC/123:
XYZ{ABCDEF/123:
XYZ-DEF:123\
```

Comparing `grep` and `awk`:

```
$ grep -wf f1 f2
ABC DEF
DEF ABC
DEF ABC XYZ
DEF|ABC XYZ
XYZ{ABC/123:
XYZ-DEF:123\

$ awk 'FNR==NR {regexes["\\y" $0 "\\y"]; next} {for (regex in regexes) if ($0 ~ regex) {print $0; break}}' f1 f2
ABC DEF
DEF ABC
DEF ABC XYZ
DEF|ABC XYZ
XYZ{ABC/123:
XYZ-DEF:123\
```

While others may be able to reduce this a bit (other than using shorter variable names) I don't think we're going to get anywhere near as 'simple' as these 7 characters: `grep -wf`

Answer (score 1):

this corresponds to

```
$ grep -wFf file1 file2
```

assuming file1 has single words

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i in a) {print; next}}' file1 file2
```

I mentioned `-F` to check for literal match (not regex). Probably an implied requirement in your case as well.